# Displaying search results from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I will paste my php code below. I have 4 jobs with web developer as the title. I essentially want it to print them in an organized table.

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';

$output="";
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job,address WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' or cname     LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

$pageTitle="Search Results";

if($count == 0){
    $output = 'There are no results';   
}else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $cname=$row["cname"];
            $title=$row["title"];

            $output .= '<div id="field">'.
                        '<h2> Search Results</h2>'.
                        '<h3><strong>'.$count.'</strong> results found searching for <strong>'."$searchq".'</strong></h3>'.

                        '<table cellpadding="5">'.
                            '<tr>'.
                            '<th> Company Name </th>'.
                            '<th><strong> Position Title </th>'.
                            '</tr>'.
                            '<td>'. $cname.' </td>'.
                            '<td>'. $title .'</td>'.
                            '<td> <button onclick="myFunction()"> Location </button> </td>'.
                            '</tr>'.
                        '</table>'.

                        '</div>';

    }
}
}
?>
```

I don't want to copy and paste the whole thing. But at the bottom where I print the ''$output'' is just:

```
<?php
print ("$output$");
?>
```

EDIT: I am pretty new at PHP so this may not be the best way to do this.  (This is not a professional site. This is just a school project.)

Screenshot:

The Map was covering up the rest of the information for some reason. So I deleted the map and this was the result.

[image]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: This is a school project. So she told us to do it this away. I am afraid if she takes a look at the code and sees it is not exactly like she did it in class, I will get points off. You know teachers don't like when you stray from the class code.

Comment: Ask your instructor about it. It is ***extremely* bad practice** to be using deprecated functions. They could be removed at ANY time, not to mention they will be low on the list of priorities for fixes if a security hole is revealed in them. Don't fall into the habit of using them and try to let your instructor know this. If they do not accept this fact then fine, continue this way, but remember that these functions should NOT be used in new code anymore. It is unfortunate that your instructor is teaching you this way, but I suppose in certain situations you can't change that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing `<tr>` tag

```
  '<table cellpadding="5">'.
   '<tr>'.
    '<th> Company Name </th>'.
    '<th><strong> Position Title </th>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<td>'. $cname.' </td>'.    //<---- here
    '<td>'. $title .'</td>'.
    '<td> <button onclick="myFunction()"> Location </button> </td>'.
    '</tr>'.
'</table>'.
```

Also did you really mean to print an entire table for each result?

probably just

```
    '<tr>'.
    '<td>'. $cname.' </td>'.   
    '<td>'. $title .'</td>'.
    '<td> <button onclick="myFunction()"> Location </button> </td>'.
    '</tr>';
```

should be in the while loop

Comment: Yea I changed that and it didn't solve the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: well then, set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to do the debugging

Comment: I just made some changes and included an image if you could take a look.